# AppCompatActivity is not fullscreen in Android 2.3

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

My AppCompatActivity take small area on screen even with built-in appcompat-styles. I have tested empty activity and when it implements AppCompatActivity it behaves the same, but when it implements Activity, all works as it should. How can I resolve or workaround this?

[image: API 10 Emulator Screenshot]

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated, which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary_accent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_color_primary</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color_secondary</item>

    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item>
    <!--<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>-->
</style>
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.zanyatocorp.checkbarcode.TestActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Seme text"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try put

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
```

on your mainfests

or check if you have Fill parrent on .xml file

**OR**

put more of your code here.

________________________________EDIT #1_________________________________________

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.zanyatocorp.checkbarcode.TestActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Seme text"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I can't use Android.Them.NoActionBar.Fullscreen style - my style must be inherent from AppCompat. Have jast added the code to the question.

Comment: fill_parent is the same as match_parent